# Pair remote ipad app with apple tv 2 that has no home sharing enabled and no hardware remote

Tags: appletv, remote-control

The hardware apple tv2 remote is lost again. And I cannot find it this time. :(. I had reset apple tv2 earlier and forgot to turn on home sharing. To make matters worse, I had setup a fixed ip for my apple tv and it only goes online with the lan cable in. When I remove the lan cable, it tells me the tv is not connected and asks me to choose settings.... which of course, I cannot do without the hardware remote.

Is there any way that I can get back control of my apple tv2 without my lost remote but from my ipad remote app solely?

Comment: More often than not, the remote can be find between the cushions of your sofa. Might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the iOS "Remote" app to control iTunes on your Mac or PC.  As part of this, you can change the audio output from the computer to any AirPlay device on the network, including the Apple TV.

You cannot, however, directly control the Apple TV's GUI.  Buy a new Apple remote, or a universal remote (love my Harmony Ones!).

If the LAN cable is a big deal, you might be able to solve that plugging the ATV into your Mac or PC (needs a micro-USB cable, though, which isn't too common yet) and then doing a restore.  This should remove the static IP, but it might also require you to walk through some setup menus when you next turn on your ATV.  That would be a problem without the remote.

I'd get a new remote, and then I think you can fix ALL the problems mentioned here.

Comment: Yeah, I tried resetting the atv2 with itunes and researched a bit more but could not get past the requirement of the hardware remote. At the end, I borrowed the remote and had the remote app enabled on my ipad.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but checkout the workaround of this problem

[Setup Apple TV (2nd Gen) with neither a remote nor home sharing turned on](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116262/setup-apple-tv-2nd-gen-with-neither-a-remote-nor-home-sharing-turned-on)