# Setup Apple TV (2nd Gen) with neither a remote nor home sharing turned on

Tags: appletv, setup

How to pair Apple TV (2nd gen) without a remote and without home sharing turned on?

Comment: I was going to say you can use the remote.app but I think you need home sharing already on

Comment: Figured out a way, see my answer :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I decided to answer my own question after 2 hours of figuring out ways around the problem that "If home sharing is not turned on, apple TV cannot be controlled with an ios device".

Note that I am talking about a 2nd gen apple TV. A 3rd gen can be worked around by http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5900?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

You actually can get the 2nd gen synced with your ios, a little sneaky but it is easily managable.

Here is what you do...

1. Connect the apple TV to your laptop and reset to factory settings on the apple TV (I did this to get a clean box + latest software update).
2. Now when apple TV powers up (just hook the HDMI to the TV and the power up the apple TV) it will ask you for a bluetooth keyboard pairing if needed (if you have one, rest is straight forward, if not go to step 3 else step 5). New versions of apple TV software ask you for this pairing, hence the restore to factory + software update on the apple TV. NOTE: Restoring may not work on a Mac running Catalina, perhaps because Apple broke the functionality when they decided to remove iTunes. On MacOS 10.15.2 it gave an "unknown error (1)" and left the Apple TV stuck in recovery mode (showing the "connect to iTunes" screen when plugged into the TV). However it seems to work fine on macOS Mojave which still has iTunes.
3. I do not own a bluetooth keyboard so I downloaded 1keyboard app from the app store for free (I own a mac, something like this should be doable for windows too).
4. Using 1Keyboard I could emulate a bluetooth keyboard functionality from my mac.
5. Once I had the keyboard connected to the apple TV, use up down etc. keys to navigate and setup your apple TV. Then go to settings and pair your ios Remote App.
6. Save 20$ by not buying the remote :-)

   Hope this helps someone.

Comment: well, actually (march 2017) 1Keyboard is 9.99$, you can use CiderTV and you can still control your Apple TV with your Mac for free :-)
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cidertv/id1065907486?mt=12

Comment: Please explain how you do step 1. If I connect the Apple TV to the computer all i see is an empty disk in finder.

Comment: its been 5 years since i posted this :) .. interesting to see that folks still find this post useful. 

you can google for how to reset appleTV to factory settings and see if that helps. good luck!

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this one. @Camaleo, thank you too. Super useful.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up Apple TV without Apple Remote:

1. Connect Apple TV as usual to the TV with the HDMI cord and power cord.
2. Connect an ethernet cable to the Apple TV and your Modem.
3. Apple TV will automatically connect to the internet.
4. Use your App Remote from your iPhone and click on remotes, use App remote
5. With the remote click on menu to get to settings and enter your network info.
6. Take the ethernet cord out and you will be able to use your app remote.

Comment: > Connect the apple TV to your laptop

How does one do this? With a crossover cable to the ethernet ports?

Comment: Crossover cable not necessary. Ordinary ethernet cable will work, as the NIC will sense and perform crossover internally.

Comment: This didn't work for me, because I couldn't enter the wifi network info while plugged into the ethernet. The following solution worked for me, pair your regular tv remote while on ethernet, then unplug and use the tv remote to add the wifi network: https://emmanuelbernard.com/blog/2013/08/15/change-the-apple-tv-wifi-settings-without-remote/

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be impossible. You might need to borrow one or buy one.

Comment: You can restore it easily, but I don't think you can control it without setting up with a remote first. A third generation can, not a second generation one.

Answer (score 0):

Buying the 1keyboard app from the mac appstore (not the ios store) worked

I'm on iMac mid 2010 model with Lion and forgot to take my apple remote tv to our holiday home.

This suggestion worked

You actually can get the 2nd gen synced with your ios, a little sneaky but it is easily managable.

Here is what you do...

Connect the apple TV to your laptop and reset to factory settings on the apple TV (I did this to get a clean box + latest software update).

Now when apple TV powers up (just hook the HDMI to the TV and the power up the apple TV) it will ask you for a bluetooth keyboard pairing if needed (if you have one, rest is straight forward, if not go to step 3 else step 5). New versions of apple TV software ask you for this pairing, hence the restore to factory + software update on the apple TV.

Here comes the cool part...
I do not own a bluetooth keyboard so I downloaded 1keyboard app from the app store for free (I own a mac, something like this should be doable for windows too).

Using 1Keyboard I could emulate a bluetooth keyboard functionality from my mac.
Once I had the keyboard connected to the apple TV, use up down etc. keys to navigate and setup your apple TV. Then go to settings and pair your ios Remote App.

Save 20$ by not buying the remote :-)

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

For those of us lucky enough to have a Samsung Galaxy phone with infrared sensor - here is the easiest solution.  Download the app from Google called "Apple TV Remote."  When downloaded, make sure the Apple TV and your Galaxy are connected to the same wireless.  When you open the app, your screen will look just like a gigantic silver Apple TV remote.  Just push it normally and your Apple TV will IMMEDIATELY RESPOND.   No pairing.  No home-sharing nonsense.  No need for an ethernet to connect AppleTV to your computer.
Just download and click.  Done.