# How to set up an iPhone or iPad to act as an Apple TV (4K) remote?

Tags: appletv, remote-control, remote.app

I can't find the Apple TV (4K) remote, and [tried to set up my iPhone or iPad as the remote](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201664).  But the Apple TV was on a different Wifi router before, and the iPhone and iPad remote app turned the wheel repeatedly and can't find the Apple TV device.

Is there any way to make it work?  Such as moving the iPhone or iPad 2 feet away from my Apple TV and have them "hooked up"?  I guess one possibility was if that Apple TV sent a token to iCloud for my account long before, and can let me download that token to my remote app to authenticate it is the same user trying to use the remote functionality but I guess such functionality is not there (yet)?  Is there any method at all?

A side note is, if a new remote needs to be purchased, I supposed it can still hook up to my existing Apple TV (4K), or else there really is no point in selling a remote by itself?

Answer (score 1):

From the link you referenced, it tells you *exactly* what's required to use your iOS device as an AppleTV Remote

> **1. Check that your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch is on the same Wi-Fi network as your Apple TV or AirPlay 2-compatible smart TV**

You need to have *both* the iOS device and the AppleTV on the same network.

> Is there any way to make it work? Such as moving the iPhone or iPad 2 feet away from my Apple TV and have them "hooked up"? I guess one possibility was if that Apple TV sent a token to iCloud for my account long before, and can let me download that token to my remote app to authenticate it is the same user trying to use the remote functionality but I guess such functionality is not there (yet)? Is there any method at all?

Proximity and tokens are not methods that have been implemented so while it an interesting concept, it simply doesn't exist.

> A side note is, if a new remote needs to be purchased, I supposed it can still hook up to my existing Apple TV (4K), or else there really is no point in selling a remote by itself?

Yes.  You can (re)pair a new Apple Remote with your existing AppleTV.  You can get more info from the Apple Support document [If you lost the remote for your AppleTV](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208492).

Comment: And to add - some smart TV remotes can also control Apple TV

Comment: That true @ReneLarsen, but I'm keeping the answer Apple centric since the crux of the question was connecting iOS devices to an AppleTV.

Comment: But the Apple TV was using a network on a different router, I think, and the ISP came and replaced it some 6 months ago. So the iPhone / iPad and the Apple TV are on different Wifi.  But actually I think the Apple TV was also on an Apple 802.11ac access point, but it looks like it didn't connect to it (or else the iPhone's remote app won't have the wheel that keep on spinning).  One other page on Internet says it is a catch-22: I need an Apple TV remote first to make it work with the iPhone's remote app...

Comment: and then, it seems I might be able to to this: use a really long Ethernet cable to connect from my current Wifi router to the Apple TV, and now my iPhone and iPad can be on the same network...

Comment: That last comment is quite confusing.  The bottom line is that your iPad, iPhone, or iPod ***must*** be on the same network.  The ISP coming out and changing the router is not really relevant because your AppleTV and your iOS device need to be connected to that new router.  "one other page on the Internet" isn't really helpful, because I have no idea to what you're referring to so I can validate what it says.  The links I supplied in the answer are direct from Apple - reference those first.

Comment: Isn't it true that the Apple TV and the iPhone has to be on the same Wifi network? I haven't used the Apple TV for more than half a year. So its Wifi setting is with the old Wifi router

Comment: *Isn't it true that the Apple TV and the iPhone has to be on the same Wifi network?*  I'm having a hard time understanding how I'm miscommunicating this to you.  I've referenced this three times in the answer and  in the comments.  ***Yes.  Your AppleTV and iPhone must be on the same network.***

Comment: Because as I understood it, the "iPhone and Apple TV have to be on the same Wifi network".  Read your own last comment " The bottom line is that your iPad, iPhone, or iPod must be on the same network."

Comment: So the iPhone and Apple TV have to be on the same network. And without the original Apple TV, there is no way to make it on the same Wifi network. So it won't work, unless if I bring a long Ethernet cable and plug it into the Apple TV.

Comment: You can connect your AppleTV to the *new* network:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204400

Comment: but I will have to have an Apple TV remote to do what is on that page

Comment: See this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116262/setup-apple-tv-2nd-gen-with-neither-a-remote-nor-home-sharing-turned-on